# How to find closed trajectories?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I need to find closed trajectories of a few differential equations, one of the examples is :

$$y''+(2(y')^2+y^4-1)y'+y^3=0$$

I tried to find some information about the trajectories from such a system of equations:
\begin{cases} y'=x  \\ x'=-2x^3-y^4x+x+y^3 \end{cases} 
But it seems to be quite complicated and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: One obvious solution is $y(t) = 0$. There are no other constant solutions, nor polynomial solutions (you can check via a degree argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curve $2(y′)^2+y^4=1$ contains a solution. Indeed let $g(y,y')=2(y′)^2+y^4-1$, then the differential equation is
$$
\frac{d}{dx}g(y,y')=4y'(y''+y^3)=-4(y')^2·g(y,y').
$$
that is, any solution with $g(y_0,y'_0)=0$ stays on that curve.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more? I understand the calculations, but I think I don't get the idea.

Comment: There is not much to explain, one has just to reverse engineer the construction of the differential equation. It is just a "fortunate coincidence" that such a $g$ exists. If it were $…+3y^2$ then one could probably still argue with Poincare-Bendixon and the stability of $y\equiv 0$ or a Ljapunov potential that closed solutions exist, but there would be most certainly no easy formulas for the curve.

Comment: Then we just say that the curve $2(y')^2+y^4=1$ is the closed trajectory?
Thanks for help.

Comment: No, the solution of this implicit ODE is the closed trajectory. Theoretically you have to show that the trajectory reaches every point of this curve.

Comment: I would also add to @LutzL comment that each time I see not so complex (or even repetitive) expression in ODEs, I have an itchy feeling to equate it to zero and see what happens :)